# Automatic Calculation Of Numeric Three Input Field

Tags: javascript, html

Im creating three numeric input fields with automatic display calculation at the side.I'm having a hard time doing since i don't know how to use ajax.Perhaps somebody can help me implementing using javascript.

Step 1: I have a text field with a default value 100.

Step 2: I have 3 numeric inputs.If i input 20 in the first field,the default value will be deducted.If i input 30 in the second field, the default value now is 50.So if i input 50 in the third field,the default value now is zero.

How can i implement this in javascript?

```html
  <label>Remaing Point:</label>
  <input type="text" name="point" value="100" disabled>

<br><br>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <th></th>
      <th><label>Points</label></th>
    <tr> 
      <th><label>Gpa:</label></th>
      <th> <input type="number" name="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
      </tr>
    <tr> 
      <th><label>Age:</label></th>
      <th><input type="number" name="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
      </tr>
<tr> 
      <th><label>Needs:</label></th>
      <th><input type="number" name="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please show your Javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want vanilla JS, it would look something like this:

Add classname and id for javascript selectors in your HTML markup:

```
 <label>Remaing Point:</label>
  <input type="text" name="point" value="100" id="remaining" disabled>

<br><br>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <th></th>
      <th><label>Points</label></th>
    <tr> 
      <th><label>Gpa:</label></th>
      <th> <input type="number" name="point" class="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
      </tr>
    <tr> 
      <th><label>Age:</label></th>
      <th><input type="number" name="point" class="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
      </tr>
<tr> 
      <th><label>Needs:</label></th>
      <th><input type="number" name="point" class="point" min="1" max="100"></th>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

With JavaScript you then bind change event listeners on the input fields:

```
    var points = document.getElementsByClassName('point');
var remaining = document.getElementById('remaining');

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].addEventListener('change', function() {

        var inputPoints = getInputPoints();

        remaining.value = 100 - inputPoints;

    });
}

function getInputPoints() {

    var inputPoints = 0;

    for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {

        var inputPoint = points[j].value || 0;

        inputPoints += parseInt(inputPoint);

    }

    return inputPoints;

}
```

Comment: good solution, but it returns NaN (at least when I run it in IE11) because every time it checks it adds the values of any blank inputs, which are not numbers.  I'd suggest wrapping the `inputPoints += parseInt(points[j].value);` line in an `if` statement like this:   `if (!isNaN(points[j].value) && points[j].value != "") { }`

Comment: @freginold - Sir thank you much for the help.The code now is running fine.

Comment: @Kees van Lierop - Sir your code really helps solving my problem with the help of freginold additional code.Thank you so much sir!

Comment: @freginold thanks for your suggestion, I will edit my answer! :)

Comment: @freginold Exactly as how Kontsnor suggested, defaulting to zero is better readable and resulting to the same outcome

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment yet, so in response to freginolds comment:

I would rewrite the function as:

```
function getInputPoints() {

    var inputPoints = 0;

    for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {

        inputPoints += parseInt(points[j].value || 0);

    }

    return inputPoints;

}
```

Just because it's shorter, and I like the way it looks!

Comment: good solution, more concise and easier to read.  only thing I would mention is that if you mix integers and text (i.e. 3d33) it starts to get a little wonky.  but OP didn't mention filtering out text as a requirement, so it's not an issue.

Comment: Oh you could also do parseInt(points[j].value || 0) || 0. That way you also default to 0 if outcome is NaN